# Missing spaces and newlines in MSDN code examples

Tags: c#, vb.net, xaml, msdn

Recently I have noticed that most of the code examples on MSDN are missing vital formatting characters such as spaces and newlines.

For example, this page on [the Setter.TargetName property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.setter.targetname.aspx) has some example XAML but it is not formatted, and there are no spaces between element names and attributes:

```
<Stylex:Key="Slider_Thumb"TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}"><SetterProperty="OverridesDefaultStyle"Value="true"/><SetterProperty="Width"Value="14"/><SetterProperty="Height"Value="14"/><SetterProperty="Template"><Setter.Value><ControlTemplateTargetType="{x:Type Thumb}"><GridWidth="14"Height="14"><EllipseFill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/><EllipseStroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"StrokeThickness="1"x:Name="ThumbCover"><Ellipse.Fill><LinearGradientBrushEndPoint="0,1"StartPoint="0,0"><LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops><GradientStopColor="#CCFFFFFF"Offset="0"/><GradientStopColor="#00000000"Offset=".5"/><GradientStopColor="#66000000"Offset="1"/></LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops></LinearGradientBrush></Ellipse.Fill></Ellipse></Grid><ControlTemplate.Triggers><TriggerProperty="IsDragging"Value="true"><SetterTargetName="ThumbCover"Property="Fill"><Setter.Value><LinearGradientBrushEndPoint="0,1"StartPoint="0,0"><LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops><GradientStopColor="#CCFFFFFF"Offset="1"/><GradientStopColor="#00000000"Offset=".5"/><GradientStopColor="#66000000"Offset="0"/></LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops></LinearGradientBrush></Setter.Value></Setter></Trigger></ControlTemplate.Triggers></ControlTemplate></Setter.Value></Setter></Style>
```

Is anybody else having this problem, and is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: I have noticed the same, but your question seems to be off-topic.

Comment: I have the same problem too, but the question proably does not belong here. Use http://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Edit -> Format Document?

Comment: OK, I take the point that this question probably breaks SO rules about being off-topic and not belonging here, but if I can go out on a limb I do think it's better here than not here. I searched Google for some time trying to find other occurrences of this problem and nothing came up, leading me to think it was something peculiar about my setup. Now the answers to this question has satisfied that point and will be immediately visible to anyone else searching for a similar problem. Less time wasted = a good thing.

Comment: Given that the answer involves a configuration fix in Visual Studio, and it is permitted to ask questions about configuration common developer tools, I'm going to agree with Stephen and suggest this is left open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable `Auto-Formatting event` in your VS for `paste from clipboard`(Tools -> Options) -

[image]

It will format your xaml as soon you paste code in your XAML file but you need to fix some spacing issues manually.

Comment: OK thanks for the heads up on auto-formatting, that must be the best I can do at the moment. It does seem very surprising that this is happening though. I will send some Feedback to Microsoft, on the extreme unlikely chance that they are unaware of the problem!